# JavaScript - Combining 3 arrays and keeping same index

Tags: javascript, arrays, mapping

I am attempting to combine the 3 arrays I have into one array, but also keep the same index of the array. I am combining the objects of the array using the `.map()` method.

```js
const revenueArr = [{title: 'online', revenue: 34321, revenueGrowth: 3.2},{title: 'retail', revenue: 321, revenueGrowth: 1.2} ] 

const employArr = [ { employGrowth: 0.2 }, {employGrowth: -1.2} ]


const businessArr = [ {businessGrowth: 2.8}, {businessGrowth: 1.6} ] 


const allData = revenueArr.map(function (title, revenue, revenueGrowth, index) {
        return {
            title: title,
            revenue: revenue,
            revenueGrowth: revenueGrowth,
            employGrowth: employArr[index],
            businessGrowth: businessArr[index]
        };
    })  

console.log(allData)
```

At the moment my `allData` is returning, `businessGrowth and employGrowth` undefined, meanwhile having `title` return the entire 3 objects instead of just the `title` from `revenueArr`

I am expecting an outcome like this:

`allData = [ {title: 'online', revenue: '34321', revenueGrowth: 3.2, employGrowth: 0.2, businessGrowth: 2.8} ]` having all objects combine together into the same index.

Comment: try `forEach()` on `revenueArr` and simply replace `return` into `append` on all data after you initialize it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use the spread operator and map

```js
const revenueArr = [{title: 'online', revenue: 34321, revenueGrowth: 3.2},{title: 'retail', revenue: 321, revenueGrowth: 1.2} ] 

const employArr = [ { employGrowth: 0.2 }, {employGrowth: -1.2} ]


const businessArr = [ {businessGrowth: 2.8}, {businessGrowth: 1.6} ] 


const allData = revenueArr.map((it, index) => {
    return { ...it, ...employArr[index], ...businessArr[index]}
}) 

console.log(allData)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could collect all arrays in an array and reduce the items by spreading all objects into a new object.

```js
const
    revenue = [{ title: 'online', revenue: 34321, revenueGrowth: 3.2 }, { title: 'retail', revenue: 321, revenueGrowth: 1.2 }],
    employ = [{ employGrowth: 0.2 }, { employGrowth: -1.2 }],
    business = [{ businessGrowth: 2.8 }, { businessGrowth: 1.6 }] ,
    result = [revenue, employ, business]
        .reduce((a, b) => a.map((o, i) => ({ ...o, ...b[i] })));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```